# Hadoop - Managing multiple input/output files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm facing problems managing multiple input files.

I have many in `.../input/` folder and a mapreduce job which I want to be executed for each of my input files, so that every input file has its own output (in `.../output/`).

Now, I tried searching on the Net but many pages are very old and I can't get a working method. Any methods/classes which I can use to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to specify a input file instead of directory, and each MR job you need to specify a output directory

Comment: Oh is it that easy?